Why I can only see white screen with flutter logo
When I run, all I can see is a fluttering logo on white screen. I do all the basic stuff like flutter clean, run & restart etc..
I do not have any code errors. I literally search everywhere and try many things like build apk no shrink run --release. But this does not make any difference. I sometimes get white screen  with a flutter logo. I have √  Build build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. This but somehow can not work that in mobile emulator
 flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Note: C:\Users\subas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\background_fetch-1.3.3\android\src\main\java\com\transistorsoft\flutter\backgroundfetch\BackgroundFetchPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             46,1s
√  Build build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter (16839): Server running on http://localhost:8080
I/WebViewFactory(16839): Loading com.google.android.webview version 113.0.5672.136 (code 567263637)
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...                     209ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

A Dart VM Service on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:54589/hR4xsbh0134=/
W/ziparchive(16839): Unable to open '/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive(16839): Unable to open '/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.dm': No such file or directory
W/le.near_pay_app(16839): Entry not found
D/nativeloader(16839): Configuring clns-7 for other apk /data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand
D/nativeloader(16839): Configuring clns-8 for other apk /data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/WebViewGoogle.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:54589/hR4xsbh0134=/
W/le.near_pay_app(16839): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(16839): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(16839): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(16839): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(16839): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/cr_WVCFactoryProvider(16839): Loaded version=113.0.5672.136 minSdkVersion=29 isBundle=false multiprocess=true packageId=2
I/cr_VariationsUtils(16839): Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.near_pay_app/app_webview/variations_seed_new"
I/cr_VariationsUtils(16839): Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.near_pay_app/app_webview/variations_seed"
I/cr_LibraryLoader(16839): Successfully loaded native library
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder(16839): Flushed 8 samples from 8 histograms.
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(16839): Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10190; state: DISABLED
D/AutofillManager(16839): Fill dialog is enabled:false, hints=[password, passwordAuto, creditCardNumber, creditCardSecurityCode, creditCardExpirationDate]
E/chromium(16839): [ERROR:simple_file_enumerator.cc(21)] opendir /data/user/0/com.example.near_pay_app/cache/WebView/Default/HTTP Cache/Code Cache/js: No such file or directory (2)
E/chromium(16839): [ERROR:simple_index_file.cc(614)] Could not reconstruct index from disk
E/chromium(16839): [ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(749)] Simple Cache Backend: cache directory inaccessible right after creation; path: /data/user/0/com.example.near_pay_app/cache/WebView/Default/HTTP Cache/Code Cache/wasm
E/chromium(16839): [ERROR:disk_cache.cc(205)] Unable to create cache
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(16839): Compat change id reported: 214741472; UID 10190; state: DISABLED
I/Choreographer(16839): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/ProfileInstaller(16839): Installing profile for com.example.near_pay_app


main.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:near_pay_app/modules/home/pages/core/home_page.dart';
import 'package:near_pay_app/modules/home/pages/core/login_page.dart';
import 'package:near_pay_app/services/core/lib_initialization_service.dart';
import 'package:near_pay_app/services/user_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:near_pay_app/l10n/app_localizations.dart';

void main() async {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await initFlutterChainLib(); // initFlutterChainLib fonksiyonunu çağırarak asset yükleme işlemlerini gerçekleştirin
    final isAuthorized = await checkIfUserAuthorized(); // Kullanıcının yetkilendirilip yetkilendirilmediğini kontrol edin

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]).then((_) => runApp(MyApp(isAuthorized: isAuthorized)));
  }, (error, stack) {
    
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? isAuthorized;
  
  const MyApp({super.key, required this.isAuthorized});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserService(isAuthorized as Dio)), 
        
      ],
      child: ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(360, 690), 
        builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Your App Title',
          localizationsDelegates: const [
            AppLocalizations.delegate, 
          ],
          supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
          home: isAuthorized == true ? const HomePage() : const LoginPage(), 
          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you share your code?

I think you have problem with main function, please share your code

okey I am adding main.dart

I added main.dart
